# Querying date in xml in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CallHistoryBasedOnPersonInfoPerEvent]
(
 @LastName varchar(50)
,@FirstName varchar(50)
,@Gender varchar(20)
,@StartDate varchar(20)
,@EndDate varchar(20) = null
)
AS
BEGIN 
SELECT     
    *
FROM         
        CallerInformation 
    INNER JOIN
        ActivityLog ON CallerInformation.CallerID = ActivityLog.CallerID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CaseStatus ON CallerInformation.CaseStatusID = CaseStatus.CaseStatusID
WHERE     
        (ActivityLog.ActivityID = 1) 
    AND
        ActivityLog.SearchParameter.value('(/Root/PersonSearch/LastName)[1]','varchar(50)') = @LastName
    AND
        ActivityLog.SearchParameter.value('(/Root/PersonSearch/FirstName)[1]','varchar(50)') = @FirstName
    AND
        ActivityLog.SearchParameter.value('(/Root/PersonSearch/Gender)[1]','varchar(20)') = @Gender
    AND
        ActivityLog.SearchParameter.value('(/Root/PersonSearch/StartDate)[1]','varchar(20)') = @StartDate
    AND
        ActivityLog.SearchParameter.value('(/Root/PersonSearch/EndDate)[1]','varchar(50)') = @EndDate
END
```

In table `ActivityLog`, `SearchParameter` is a `xml` column. The xml is stored there in this format

```
<Root>
    <PersonSearch>
        <CallerID>1249</CallerID>
        <StartDate>2013-01-16T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <FirstName>t</FirstName>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <DOBDay>0</DOBDay>
        <DOBMonth>0</DOBMonth>
        <AgeRangeStart>33</AgeRangeStart>
        <AgeRangeEnd>44</AgeRangeEnd>
        <Country>United States</Country>
        <UserName>nojha</UserName>
    </PersonSearch>
</Root>
```

Based on the joins in my stored procudure I have to select records in `ActivityLog`. The `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, `Startdate` and `Enddate` is in the XMl.

Now I am facing issue only with dates. When I provide dates I get no records when I am executing the stored procedure.

The `startDate` that I am sending through my code is in this format `1/16/2013 12:00:00 AM`.

**I know there is some mismatch. I tried few things. I removed the time in Xml and also convert the parameter `@startdate` to date. It did not work. Then I changed the `@startdate` date to `varchar(20)`. It did not work.**

Where am I going wrong

Comment: @marc_s - Interesting that you'd use the duck typing defintion for a (rather strongly) typed language. In my experience, working with a date in two different systems can be extremely difficult - sometimes converting them both to a string representation is the only way to compare them.

Comment: @marc_s please c the higlighted section. As i mentioned i convedted to date before converting to string. but both the tries where unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it **correctly**, it works **just fine** - see here:

```
-- define a table variable for demo purposes
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, XMLDATA XML)

-- insert three rows with different <StartDate> values
INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES
   (1, '<Root><PersonSearch><StartDate>2013-01-16T00:00:00</StartDate></PersonSearch></Root>'),
   (2, '<Root><PersonSearch><StartDate>2013-01-18T00:00:00</StartDate></PersonSearch></Root>'),
   (3, '<Root><PersonSearch><StartDate>2013-01-16T00:00:00</StartDate></PersonSearch></Root>')

-- declare a search value, e.g. like the parameter of the stored procedure    
DECLARE @SearchDate DATE = '20130116'

-- select the rows from the table 
SELECT 
    ID
FROM
    @table
WHERE   
    XmlData.value('(/Root/PersonSearch/StartDate)[1]','date') = @SearchDate
```

I get the `ID` #1 and #3 selected - just as expected.

So if you really use `DATE` for dates as you should anways, then **it just works**.

Comment: Won't this also lead to a table scan?  Or is there a way to index just the inner bits of the XML?

Comment: @MattJohnson: if the XML isn't indexed (you *can* have XML indices in SQL Server), then yes, this most likely results in a table scan. If this is a frequent query, one could use a user-defined function to extract that `StartDate` from the XML and store it as a **persisted, computed column** on the table itself, thus enabling it to be indexed as needed